# FireStore Not generating link to add compound query - only saying no index found- No Link to create index - Manual index not working

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-app-check

Major breaking bug in new FireStore. No Link is generating or printing in log for to create compound index for query multiple . It used to generate and click on this link direct building index. Now no link is generating and even **create manually index in Firebase console not working** .

Getting exception :

**`com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: no matching index found.`**

contacted Firebase Team and waiting for their response. It is blocking our live App update.

And created issue in buganizer , ref https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193552922

Comment: Please see the [ask] help page and [The perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet.

Comment: any update on this, I see this issue post the recent android update

Comment: Still no solution , created issue in issue tracker  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193552922

Comment: Follow issue on github https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5152

Comment: I am having similar issue on ios